# URL Rewrite without authenticating

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using IIS7.  Everything works great when the user is logged in.  But if I log out, and go to:

`dev.local/EN/Login.aspx`

the URL rewrite is not doing it's job.  First, it redirects to

`dev.local/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/EN/Login.aspx`

Why?  How can I make the URL rewrite work before the redirect?

web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".MyForm" loginUrl="Login.aspx" domain="dev.local" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="LanguageUrlRewrite">
                <match url="^(.+)/(es|en|fr|pt)/(.+)?(.+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}?Language={R:2}&amp;{R:4}" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anonymous access enabled. Authentication would trump the rewrite.  The way you have it setup you should only be able to get to pages if you login.  Otherwise, the only page you can get to without logging in is the login page.